# Remove escape characters string using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the escape charecters from a string using jquery.

I know about the "escape()" in jquery but the issue is

For example I want to remove the escape charecters from the string "http://www.abc.com" if we

use escape() we get the result like this 'http%3A//www.abc.com'  but i want the result like

'http//www.abc.com'. How it possible using jquery?

Comment: escape() is not jQuery, its part of javascript and is deprecated now.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`escape()` encodes the special characters! To remove the characters, use for example `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`.

In the `regex`-part you can insert all of the special character you want to remove.

Comment: Answer should include example.

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing in jQuery about unescpaing.

Core javascript has [escape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.escape) and [unescape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.unescape) function.

```
var url = 'http://www.abc.com';

var escaped_url = escape(url);

console.log(escaped_url); // logs 'http%3A//www.abc.com'

console.log(unescape(escpaed_url)) // logs 'http://www.abc.com'
```

i.e.

`unescape(escape('http://www.abc.com'))  === 'http://www.abc.com'`

Comment: this only an example my aim is create string with no special charecter

Comment: just `unescape` it. You will be able to create a string with no special character

Comment: `unescape` is deprecated now. What to use for same results? decodeURI* functions are for URI :) But I have to decode body of the response.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex? `replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')` function? Amend to characters you want to keep

Comment: ':' is given only as example i want to remove all special  charecters

Comment: actually this is for to create variables from file names that is file names may be like "absc(1)" or "absdf qw1" i want to strip the special charecters and get the name like this "absc1" or "absdfqw1"